# Running Conditionals / For Loop in PG Promise with ColumnSet

Tags: pg-promise

I'm trying to put together some code that iterates over all the fields on a form and then inserts the data into a column set to be inserted. The problem im running into though is that it seems like PG-Promise isn't calling the function to run the validator. Any idea how to solve this? Here is the code i'm tyring to run.

```
exports.detailedbudgetpost = async function (req, res, next) {

  const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(["attrib_id", "value", "response_id"], {
    table: "formquestionresponse",
  });

  const values = [
    {
      attrib_id: 20,
      value: companyDetails.company_name,
      response_id: insertedForm.response_id,
    },
    {
      attrib_id: 19,
      value: companyDetails.first_name + " " + companyDetails.last_name,
      response_id: insertedForm.response_id,
    }
  ];

  const arrayCheck = (values, insertedformresponse) => {
    for (var x = 1; x >= 7; x++) {
      if (isEmpty(req.body[`goal${x}`]) == false) {
        values.push({
          attrib_id: 23,
          value: req.body[`goal${x}`],
          response_id: insertedformresponse,
        });
      }

      if (isEmpty(req.body[`descriptionofneed${x}`]) == false) {
        values.push({
          attrib_id: 24,
          value: req.body[`descriptionofneed${x}`],
          response_id: insertedformresponse,
        });
      }
    }
    return values;
  };

  db.tx(async (t) => {
    const companyDetails = await db.one(
      "SELECT company_name, c.id, first_name, last_name FROM company c INNER JOIN useraccount u on c.id = u.company_id WHERE u.username = $1",
      [req.user.user]
    );

    const insertedForm = await db.one(
      "INSERT INTO formresponse(company_id, form_id) VALUES ($1, 3) RETURNING response_id",
      [companyDetails.id]
    );

    arrayCheck(values, insertedForm.response_id);

    const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs);
    const recordsResponse = await t.none(query);
  })
    .then((results) => {
      req.flash("info", "Your form has been succesfully submitted. Thank you!");
      res.redirect("/thanks");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      req.flash(
        "error",
        "An error has occured. Please try again or submit a support ticket."
      );
      res.redirect("/");
    });
};
```

Comment: `PG-Promise isn't calling the function to run the validator`. What function? What validator? What `pg-promise` has to do with that? Nothing is clear from your question, except one thing - you are not even using the transaction right (see [chaining-queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries)), i.e. you are misusing transaction context by using `db` instead of `t` of the transaction context. Queries inside transaction must be executed against the transaction context, and not the root `db` context.

Comment: I figured it out, it was a stupid error on my part and good catch with the db instead of t. Thanks for the great software though!